# spree commerce API - disable authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Looking to disable authentication for Spree commerce cart on rails, testing cart on local build, getting 401 un-authorization error

spree docs show this, not sure how to set this to false

> >
>   Spree::Api::Config[:requires_authentication]

Answer (score 1):

you can include in the existing Spree initializer `config/initializers/spree.rb` but i'm not positive where Spree would prefer it reside.

```
# spree.rb
Spree.config do |config|
  config.site_name = "Spree Demo Site"
end

Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"

Spree::Api::Config[:requires_authentication] = false
```